# MongoDB geoHaystack Indexes Use Case

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, geospatial

MongoDB has a a geo index called geoHaystack which the site says is optimized for "small" areas (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geohaystack/). This is quite a vague description and I am unsure if it fits my use case. What is considered small? I will need to search for points within 1km and also 2km. There will at most be 100 points inside of these searches, is this considered small? The writes and reads will be approximately 25:75. Is this type of index the best for my use case or is my area too big and should go with a regular 2d index?